# Extjs 4 Category axis grouping

Tags: extjs, grouping, categories

When I tried to create a scatter extjs chart I've come across such a problem:
Category axis the names are not grouped (array elements with identic name are not treated as the same). It seems like the chart tries to draw it as a mathmatical function (with only one element of y for each x) but I deliberately chose scatter chart to avoid it.

Tried to find the anser in google but the only result I found is just to accept...

This is the code:

```
window.store_direct = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
fields: ['id','line','bidder','data0','data1','data2','data3'],
data: [
{'line':1000.00,'id':0,'bidder':'Пок','data0':1000.00},

{'line':800.00,'id':1,'bidder':'Пок','data0':800.00},

{'line':950.00,'id':0,'bidder':'Брг','data1':950.00},

{'line':599.00,'id':1,'bidder':'Брг','data1':599.00},

{'line':1.00,'id':2,'bidder':'Брг','data1':1.00},

{'line':500.00,'id':0,'bidder':'КВВ','data2':500.00},

{'line':900.00,'id':0,'bidder':'Buy4','data3':900.00},

{'line':600.00,'id':1,'bidder':'Buy4','data3':600.00}
],
```

});

```
var chart = function () {
var win = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    animate: true,
    hidden: false,
    maximizable: true,
    title: 'Процесс торгов',
    layout: 'fit',
    items:{xtype: 'chart',style: 'background:#fff;',animate: true,store: store_direct,shadow: true,legend: {position: 'right'},
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['data0','data1','data2','data3'],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        title: 'Sample Values',
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['bidder'],
        title: 'Sample Metrics'
    }],
    series: [
     {
        type: 'Scatter',
        highlight: {size: 7,radius: 7},
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'bidder',
        yField: 'data0',
        markerConfig: {type: 'cross',size: 4,radius: 4,'stroke-width': 0}
    }
    , {
        type: 'Scatter',
        highlight: {size: 7,radius: 7},
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'bidder',
        yField: 'data1',
        markerConfig: {type: 'cross',size: 4,radius: 4,'stroke-width': 0}
    }
    , {
        type: 'Scatter',
        highlight: {size: 7,radius: 7},
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'bidder',
        yField: 'data2',
        markerConfig: {type: 'cross',size: 4,radius: 4,'stroke-width': 0}
    }
    , {
        type: 'Scatter',
        highlight: {size: 7,radius: 7},
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'bidder',
        yField: 'data3',
        markerConfig: {type: 'cross',size: 4,radius: 4,'stroke-width': 0}
    }
             ]
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ext JS charts' terminology is a bit specific; in this case you need to configure your Series. There are some good examples for Charts, take a look: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example

Comment: Well, I've tried to configure them but fail to achieve what desired. And see no difference between my series discription and discription here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/charts/Scatter - Renderer.html

Comment: Forgot to tell I've also tried to use such a string "categoryNames:'Buy4,КВВ,Пок,Брг' " in either "series" or "axes". But both variants failed.